# Shift Key Random behaviour on MacBook Air with Big Sur

Tags: keyboard, keybindings, big-sur, safe-mode

Recently I upgraded to Big Sur on my MacBook Air (13 inch, early 2015 model) and it worked fine for a couple of days. Suddenly the left Shift key shows some random behaviour. Sometimes, it is always on leading to Safe Boot. Some times it is disabled. This behaviour appears randomly and creates a lot of trouble. I checked Internet and tried a few suggestions like installing keymap applications, removing the shift key physically etc. Nothing gave a permanent solutions. Then I removed MacOS completely and installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and all keys including the SHIFT key worked perfectly. Which implied that there is no hardware issue with the key. I again installed MacOS (Big Sur) and now the issue (the random behaviour) is back. Is it due to some virus attack? Any solutions?

As per Tetsujin's suggestion I installed Key Codes. The left Shift key didn't give any response. The right Shift key response is shown in the figure attached.

[image]

Comment: The OS isn't running at the point you enter into a safe mode boot - you're pretty much running from 'ROM' at that point, so my money is on the keyboard.

Comment: @Tetsujin Yes I also doubted that. But when I installed Ubuntu 18.04, as discussed in the post, everything worked as normal! So I don't think it is a hardware issue. After installing the Big Sur teh last time it went to safe boot only once.

Comment: Sure, but it's really hard to prove a negative, so you have to sometimes go with your 'gut feel'… & mine says keyboard. Try running [Key Codes](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/key-codes/id414568915?mt=12) (freeware) & see if you can see anything suspect

Comment: @Tetsujin I installed Key Codes as you suggested. But the left Shift key doesn't show any response. However, if I use mouse to select some text in a page, it is showing the behaviour as if Shift key is pressed and holding! Similarly if I click on a new link, a new window opens (as if I pressed Shift key and clicked the mouse)!

Comment: That would reinforce my opinion that the key is busted, I'm afraid. Hard to make it work could be cleanable/fixable, hard to make it **stop** working is usually a new keyboard. You could try cleaning it up, but don't expect miracles.

Comment: @Tetsujin In that case how it works when I install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS? This behaviour only lead me to belive that the hardware key is in good condition. Seems I need to go back to Ubuntu!

Comment: For process of elimination, you'd need to get an app equivalent to KeyCodes for nix. KeyCodes on Mac is telling me your key is permanently pressed.

Comment: @Tetsujin But if it is permanently pressed, then the key codes should reflect that ...right?

Comment: keys have 4 states (start, held, end, untouched), based on two bitswitches (levels, edges) - in short, if the key is down when KeyCodes launches, it will never see the state change for edges so will never know the key is held. If you then press a letter, KeyCodes will recognise that the letter was shifted, even though it didn't see the shift being pressed.

Comment: @Tetsujin  But when I press the right Shift Key everything is normal. I get capital and small letters as expected for some time. Then randomly at some point of time all caps appears!

Comment: That reinforces that the problem is intermittent - it really all adds up to a busted key.

Comment: @Tetsujin is there a option to disable left Shift key permanently?

Comment: Short of physically breaking it, no.